# Bibliography First Name Sorting

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I have a little problem with my bibliography's order. I want the `biblatex` package to sort the references alphabetically by the First name of each author and then by their Last Name.

Here is my code sorting by Last Name:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
%style=numeric,
bibencoding=ascii
style=alphabetic
%style=reading
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
```

Please help me to configure this so it sorts by First Name then Last Name.

Comment: For Example if i have this refernces : 
A. Einstein ....
A. Camus ....
I. Newton ...
M. Levy ....
Then the sort in my bibliography will be like this :
[1] A. Camus ...
[2] A. Einstein ...
[3] I. Newton ...
[4] M. Levy ...

Comment: I don't think any such option exists. Why on earth do you want this?

Comment: Well Why not ^^ ? But if it's not possible then I will keep my previous sort.

Comment: @RedOne Are you really sure this is a good idea? I have two concerns (at least for the Western Hemisphere, may be different for other cultures): 1) besides the immediate family and circle of friends people are much more likely to know the last name of a person and might not know the first name - thus they will probably search for a last name in the bibliography. 2) As this is a very uncommon way to sort, people will probably not expect this sorting and be confused.

Comment: You are right, but I wanted to have a complete oredering in my Bibliography, I wanted to have the sort form A to the letter Z, I didn't want to have for example : 
[1] A. Einstein ...
[2] C. Berge ...
[3] V. Hugo ...
[4] B. Pascal ... 
It's a little bit confusing, But I'll keep the Last name sorting I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Biber you can use

```
\documentclassarticle}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareSortingNamekeyScheme{
  \keypart{
    \namepart{given}
  }
  \keypart{
    \namepart{prefix}
  }
  \keypart{
    \namepart{family}
  }
  \keypart{
    \namepart{suffix}
  }
}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,cicero,nussbaum,knuth:ct:a}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example bibliography]

This will not work with BibTeX, though, as the name format there is not fully customisable.

The order will probably confuse your readers to no end, but it works.

Comment: Well, I learned something today. I don't think I'll ever use it, though.

Comment: But since there's no number in the references [1] , [2] , ... I can't use this code in this case, but I will certainly use it in others memoirs.

Comment: @RedOne I don't quite get what you mean. You can certainly also use this together with `style=numeric`.

Comment: It works with the numeric style also, I just try it, and it does what I want, Thanks.