# Plainnat like bibliography style but order by first name

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

By default, in the reference list generated by using the `plainnat`, the references are ordered by their last names.

How to order them by their first names?

Here I attach an MWE

`article.tex`

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

Test \citep{a1,a2,a3}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

`refs.bib`

```
@article{a1,
    title={Test paper 1},
    author={Albert Zwick},
    journal={Nature},
    year={2000}
}
@article{a2,
    title={Test paper 2},
    author={Christ Johnson},
    journal={Nature},
    year={2000}
}
@article{a3,
    title={Test paper 3},
    author={John Doe},
    journal={Nature},
    year={2000}
}
```

By default we will get

[image]

which are ordered by the last name. How to order by first name while sticking with `plainat`style?

Comment: `apalike` does not sort by given names either. It also sorts by the author's family (last) name, what's more it even inverts the name order in the bibliography so the family name comes first.

Comment: @moewe ah yes, I didn't even notice that. I corrected my questio now.

Comment: So you really want to sort by first names? I'm asking again, because that is *extremely* unusual (at least with Western names) and unexpected for your readers.

Comment: I understand the style might look weird, but I think at least it could be a good tex practice ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting by given (first) name is extremely unusual with Western names. With `natbib`'s authoryear style it also makes references much harder to find in the bibliography since your readers only know the family (last) names.

Anyway, to achieve the desired sorting you need to modify the `.bst` file

1. Locate `plainnat.bst` on your machine. You can do this by typing `kpsewhich plainnat.bst` into the command line/terminal. Alternatively, obtain a copy of the file from CTAN http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/plainnat.bst
2. Copy the file to a location where TeX can find it. The document directory will do fine.
3. Rename the file to `plainnat-sortby-first.bst`
4. Open the file and replace the block starting with `FUNCTION {sort.format.names}` (ll. 1207-1235 in my version) by

   ```
   FUNCTION {sort.format.names}
   { 's :=
     #1 'nameptr :=
     ""
     s num.names$ 'numnames :=
     numnames 'namesleft :=
       { namesleft #0 > }
       {
         s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
         nameptr #1 >
           {
             "   "  *
             namesleft #1 = t "others" = and
               { "zzzzz" * }
               { numnames #2 > nameptr #2 = and
                   { "zz" * year field.or.null * "   " * }
                   'skip$
                 if$
                 t sortify *
               }
             if$
           }
           { t sortify * }
         if$
         nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
         namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
       }
     while$
   }
   ```

The only change here is from `s nameptr "{vv{ } }{ll{ }}{  ff{ }}{  jj{ }}" format.name$ 't :=` to `s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=`.

5. Add your name and date and explain the modification in the comments at the top of the file.
6. Use `\bibliographystyle{plainnat-sortby-first.bst}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` in your document.

As alternative to steps 1 to 5 above, you can get `plainnat-sortby-first.bst` from https://gist.github.com/moewew/203188e9933fdac3873601770b932357.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a1,
  title   = {Test paper 1},
  author  = {Albert Zwick},
  journal = {Nature},
  year    = {2000},
}
@article{a2,
  title   = {Test paper 2},
  author  = {Christ Johnson},
  journal = {Nature},
  year    = {2000},
}
@article{a3,
  title   = {Test paper 3},
  author  = {John Doe},
  journal = {Nature},
  year    = {2000},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Test \citep{a1,a2,a3}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat-sortby-first}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Albert Zwick. Test paper 1. Nature, 2000.//Christ Johnson. Test paper 2. Nature, 2000.//John Doe. Test paper 3. Nature, 2000.]

---

If you want given-family order everywhere (not just for sorting, but also in citations), get `plainnat-firstlast.bst` from https://gist.github.com/moewew/008625af47bc58c76e2e89ef2789fa1a.

Comment: `biblatex` users will want to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/373569/35864.